# ownCloud command line client owncloudcmd

Tags: command-line, 18.04, owncloud-client

[The ownCloud documentation](https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.4/advancedusage.html) mentions a command line client `owncloudcmd` which is supposed to be installed as part of the ownCloud Client package.

I have [the `owncloud-client` package from the official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/owncloud-client) installed on Ubuntu 18.04 (version 2.4.1). The GUI client works but I cannot find this `owncloudcmd` executable.

Does anybody know why the Ubuntu package doesn't contain `owncloudcmd`, and how I can install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They split the package in two:

- [the package `owncloud-client`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/owncloud-client) holds the GUI program  `owncloud` while
- [the package `owncloud-client-cmd`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/owncloud-client-cmd) holds the CLI program `owncloudcmd`

The latter doesn’t depend on the GUI program, which probably is why they split the two – on a headless system you don’t need the GUI, so no need to install it. To use `owncloudcmd` you just need to install the aforementioned package:

```
sudo apt install owncloud-client-cmd
```

On Ubuntu 18.04 this installs version 2.4.1 of the program. If for any reason you need the current version 2.4.2 and/or updates to the current version at any time, I recommend installing [the Ubuntu PPA from software.opensuse.org](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:desktop&package=owncloud-client). Follow these steps to set it up and install the package (I simplified this a bit):

1. Remove the repository package (you may skip this step if you didn’t install it):

   ```
   sudo apt remove owncloud-client{,-cmd}
   ```
2. Add the repository:

   ```
   echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_18.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/isv:ownCloud:desktop.list
   ```
3. Add the repository key:

   ```
   wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:desktop/Ubuntu_18.04/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
4. Update the sources and install the newest package version available. As the PPA‘s version is newer, this ignores the official repository’s `owncloud-client` package:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install owncloud-client
   ```

After this `owncloud` and most notably `owncloudcmd` work out of the box:

```
$ owncloudcmd --version
ownCloud version 2.4.2 (build 9883)
Git revision d6e9755121c22b8033d18d496b0e59b7bb752b62
Using Qt 5.6.2, built against Qt 5.6.2
Using 'OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017'
```